# Gradients for partially symmetric CP decomposition of 3rd order tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, tensor-decomposition

I am interested in computing a rank-$R$ CP decomposition of a 3rd order tensor that is partially symmetric about the first 2 modes. The factorization of a vanilla CP decomposition is given below as a least squares minimization problem:

$$ \min_{A,B,C} || \mathcal{X} - [[A,B,C]]||^{2}
$$

where $\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times M \times N} $ is the tensor to approximate, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times R}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times R}$, and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times R}$ are factor matrices to estimate. [[]] denotes the sum of outer products of each of the corresponding factor matrix columns:

$$ [[A,B,C]] = \sum_{r=1}^{R} a_{r} \otimes b_{r} \otimes c_{r}
$$

Where $a_r$ is the $r$-th column of $A$, etc.

This objective can be rewritten as sub-problems corresponding to each mode:

$$ \min_{A} ||\mathcal{X}_{(1)} - A(C \odot B)^{T}||^{2} \\
\min_{B} ||\mathcal{X}_{(2)} - B(C \odot A)^{T}||^{2} \\
\min_{C} ||\mathcal{X}_{(3)} - C(B \odot A)^{T}||^{2} 
$$

where the subscript $\mathcal{X}_{(i)}$ indicates the $i$-th mode unfolding of a tensor (matricization where the mode-$i$ fibers become the columns of the resulting matrix) and $\odot$ is the Khatri-Rao product. The partial derivatives, with respect to each factor matrix, are as follows:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial A} = (\mathcal{T}_{(1)} - \mathcal{X}_{(1)})(C \odot B) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial B} = (\mathcal{T}_{(2)} - \mathcal{X}_{(2)})(C \odot A) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial C} = (\mathcal{T}_{(3)} - \mathcal{X}_{(3)})(B \odot A)
$$

where $\mathcal{T}=[[A,B,C]]$. See [here](https://www.kolda.net/publication/JChem-CPOPT%20Orig%20Submission.pdf) and [here](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-239) for details regarding all of the above derivation/implementation.

In the case of partial symmetry about the first two modes, my problem becomes:

$$ \min_{A,A,C} || \mathcal{X} - [[A,A,C]]||^{2}
$$

where $\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M \times N} $ is a the tensor to approximate, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times R}$, and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times R}$.

So, my question is, what would the partial derivatives be for the above case with partial symmetry with respect to $A$ and $C$? My actual optimization problem is more complex than this, so I want the gradients for non-linear optimization and this is the particular aspect of the objective that I have been unable to compute them. Any advise is greatly appreciated, I've been banging my head trying to figure this out - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\d{\delta} \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\E{{\cal E}} \def\T{{\cal T}}
\def\H{{\cal H}} \def\X{{\cal X}} \def\Y{{\cal M}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$First, define two extremely useful zero-one (aka indicator) tensors
$$\eqalign{
\H_{ijk} &= \begin{cases}
\o\quad{\rm if}\;\;i=j=k \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
\E_{ijkl} &= \begin{cases}
\o\quad{\rm if}\;\;i=k\;\;{\rm and}\;\;j=l \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
}$$
The latter is often written in terms of Kronecker delta symbols as
$$ \E_{ijkl} = \d_{ik}\,\d_{jl} $$
Now we can write matrix self-gradients and $\T$ using the Einstein summation convention
$$\eqalign{
&\grad{A_{ij}}{A_{kl}} \;=\; \E_{ijkl} = \d_{ik}\,\d_{jl} \\
&\T = [[A,B,C]]\qiq\T_{ijk} = \H_{pqr}\:A_{ip}\,B_{jq}\,C_{kr} \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define the tensor
$$ \Y=\T-\X \qiq d\Y=d\T $$
Write the objective function as a triple contraction product
and calculate its gradient wrt $A$
$$\eqalign{
f &= \Y_{ijk} \:\: \Y_{ijk} \\
df &= 2\,\Y_{ijk} \:\: d\T_{ijk} \\
 &= 2\,\Y_{ijk} \LR{\H_{pqr}\:\c{dA_{ip}}\,B_{jq}\,C_{kr}} \\
\grad{f}{A_{uv}}
 &= 2\,\Y_{ijk}\H_{pqr}\,\c{\d_{iu}\d_{pv}}\,B_{jq}\,C_{kr} \\
 &= 2\,\Y_{ujk}\H_{vqr}\,B_{jq}\,C_{kr} \\
}$$
Suspending the Einstein convention, you would code this as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{A_{uv}}
 &= 2 \sum_{j=\o}^M\sum_{k=\o}^N \Y_{ujk}\,B_{jv}\,C_{kv} \\
}$$
Change the definition of $\T$ as proposed in your post and re-calculate the gradient
$$\eqalign{
\T &= [[A,A,C]]\qiq\T_{ijk} = \H_{pqr}\:A_{ip}\,A_{jq}\,C_{kr} \\
df &= 2\,\Y_{ijk} \:\: d\T_{ijk} \\
 &= 2\,\Y_{ijk} \LR{\H_{pqr}\:\c{dA_{ip}}\,A_{jq}\,C_{kr}} 
  + 2\,\Y_{ijk} \LR{\H_{pqr}\:A_{ip}\:\c{dA_{jq}}\,C_{kr}} \\
 &= 2\,\Y_{ijk}\H_{pqr}C_{kr}
     \LR{\:\c{dA_{ip}}\,A_{jq} + A_{ip}\:\c{dA_{jq}}} \\
\grad{f}{A_{uv}}
 &= 2\,\Y_{ijk}\H_{pqr}C_{kr}\LR{\:\c{\d_{iu}\d_{pv}}A_{jq}+A_{ip}\c{\d_{ju}\d_{qv}}} \\
 &= 2\,\Y_{ujk}\H_{vqr}C_{kr}A_{jq}
\;+\; 2\,\Y_{iuk}\H_{pvr}C_{kr}A_{ip} \\
}$$
And this would be coded as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{A_{uv}}
 &= 2 \sum_{j=\o}^L\sum_{k=\o}^N \LR{\Y_{ujk}+\Y_{juk}}A_{jv}C_{kv} \\
}$$

Comment: thanks for that - would have never thought of the indicator tensor trick. Do you have a resource for where you learned this/refer back to?

Comment: These two zero-one tensors (and a couple of others) appear quite frequently in the solution of _Matrix Calculus_ problems. They are used to diagonalize matrices, replace Hadamard products and rearrange the order of regular matrix products.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is to use the gradients you have already calculated in the general case.
Doing so, you have
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{A}}
=
\left(\mathcal{T}_{(1)}-\mathcal{X}_{(1)}\right) 
(\mathbf{C}\boxtimes \mathbf{A}) +
\left(\mathcal{T}_{(2)}-\mathcal{X}_{(2)}\right) 
(\mathbf{C}\boxtimes \mathbf{A})
$$
where
$\boxtimes$ denotes the Khatri-Rao product.

We can check that this result agrees with Greg's answer
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A_{uv}}
=
\sum_{jk}
M_{ujk} (A_{jv}C_{kv})+
\sum_{jk}
M_{juk} (A_{jv}C_{kv})
$$